# How many times the solution will intersect the line

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello everyone I have a problem I'm struggling with :

I have the following systems :

$$
\begin{cases}
& {x}'=x+y
 \\
& {y}'= y-x
\end{cases}
$$

I found the solutions using *the Method of Matrix Exponential*,

For the first system I found :

$X_1(t) = e^{t} \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(t)&&\sin(t)\\ 
-\sin(t)&&\cos(t)
\end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}
C_1\\ 
C_2
\end{pmatrix}$

Best wishes

**Edit: ANSWERED**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each solution $X_i(t)$ you got, you should equal the first component (that is to say, the $x-$coordinate) to $0$ and see how many solutions for $t$ you get.

In the first case,
$$\frac{1}{2}e^{5t} + \frac{1}{2}e^{-t} = 0,$$
which cannot have a solution due to both terms are positive.

In the second case,
$$e^{2t}\sin(3t) = 0$$
which has infinite solutions since it is zero when $3t = k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.